# How to display an embed full-width on mobile, but 60% width on desktop

Tags: html, css

I'm not much of a coder and would like some help please. I'm looking to embed Thinglink on to this page of our website https://greenstonecreek.co.nz/try-our-beef

```
<iframe width="960" height="1379" data-original-width="1500" data-original-height="2154" src="https://www.thinglink.com/card/1350681136287711233" type="text/html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe><script async src="//cdn.thinglink.me/jse/responsive.js"></script>
```

I would like the Thinglink embed to display full width on mobile and about 60% on desktop. Can somebody please let me know what code I would use to do this?

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to do it with css only, following the following code. You can test it by running code snippet, so you can see mobile result and if you look at full screen you can see desktop result.

```css
iframe {
  width: 60vw !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XFkzRNyygfk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```